# Cloud Foundry service vs app

Tags: cloud, ibm-cloud, cloud-foundry

What is the difference between the concepts of `service`/`user provided service` and `apps` in Cloud Foundry? After all both expose URLs

So when is it recommended to create a service and when an app?

Comment: Many services expose URLs but there is no requirement that they do so. A service could expose credentials and connection values as discrete values like host, port, username, and password instead of a URL. Or a service could provide no connection details or credentials at all (e.g. a non-bindable service that only provisions resources).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The `app` sits on top of the stack and often has a user-interface. It consumes services (is built on services). The Cloud Foundry app typically runs in the browser and is accessible via an URL. There are [apps that have no route](https://docs.cloudfoundry.org/devguide/deploy-apps/manifest.html#no-route) (not an accessible URL).

A `service` provides consumable functionality. It also has an URL, so that apps or other services can reach it. A typical service is a database or a bot / conversation / dialog service, a map or some sign-on / password service.

To make it more fun, there are services that wrap an app and make the app's functionality accessible via an URL. I would recommend reading the [Cloud Foundry overview](http://docs.cloudfoundry.org/concepts/overview.html) or [Bluemix overview](https://console.ng.bluemix.net/docs/overview/whatisbluemix.html#bluemixoverviewapplications). You may also want to check out some samples [here](https://console.eu-gb.bluemix.net/catalog/?taxonomyNavigation=apps&category=blueprints) or [here](https://ibm-bluemix.github.io/) that demonstate how apps are built on services.

To answer the part about when to build a service or an app:
 - Is the functionality for an end-user? Does it have a user interface? => app
 - Is it going to be used by another app or service? => service

Comment: Thanks 1+ what is the use case of app without accesible URL ?

Comment: in addtion As app is scoped to space, what about service to space
1. service - if I implement service (using service broker api ) in dev space does it
visible in qa space
2 . user provided servcie - same question thanks

Comment: I added a link to the "no route" section. That could be daemon apps, apps running in the background. Open another topic for your follow-up questions.

Comment: I would also add that services typically have some sort of persistent state or data.  For example, a MySQL DB stores your data.  Apps in CF don't, or shouldn't, have persistent state.  They should bind with a service and use it to persist their data.

Answer (score 1):

One way to consider this is by looking at it from a dependency perspective:

> Applications typically depend on services such as databases or third-party SaaS providers. When a developer provisions and binds a service to an application, the service broker for that service is responsible for providing the service instance.
>
> **Source**: https://docs.cloudfoundry.org/concepts/architecture/#services

On the flip side, services don't tend to depend on applications.

Comment: Thanks 1+ , As app is scoped to space, what about service to space
1. service - if I implement service (using service broker api ) in dev space does it
visible in qa/space
2 . user provided servcie - same questio

Comment: I'm not sure of the answer - It may be worth posting a new question about this.